# is it ever appropriate to localize a single ascii character

Tags: localization, internationalization, ascii

When would it be appropriate to localize a single ascii character?
for instance /, or | ?

is it ever necessary to add these "strings" to the localization effort?

just want to give some people the benefit of the doubt and make sure there's not something I didn't think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are cases where these individual characters change in localization.  This is not a comprehensive list, just examples I happen to know.

1. Not every locale uses `,` to separate thousands and `.` for the decimal.  (However, these will usually be handled by your number formatter.  If you do so yourself, you're probably doing it wrong.  See this [MSDN blog post by Michael Kaplan, Number format and currency format are not always the same](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/21/431005.aspx).)
2. Not every language uses the same quotation marks (`“`, `”`, `‘` and `’`).  See [Wikipedia on Non-English Uses of Quotation Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks).  (Many of these are only easy to replace if you use full quote marks.  If you use the `"` and `'` on your keyboard to mark both the start and end of sentences, you won't know which of two symbols to substitute.)
3. In Spanish, a question or exclamation is preceded by an [inverted ? or !](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks).  `¿Question?`  `¡Exclamation!`  (Obviously, you can't fix this with a locale substitution for a single character.  Any questions or exclamations in your application should be entire strings anyway, unless you're writing some stunningly intelligent natural language generator.)

If you do find a circumstance where you need to localize these symbols, be extra cautious not to accidentally localize a symbol like `/` used as a file separator, `"` to denote a string literal or `?` for a search wildcard.

However, this has already happened with CSV files.  These may be separated by `,`, or may be separated by the local list separator.  See [What would happen if you defined your system's CSV delimiter as being a quotation mark?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/63620)

Comment: most correct answer in the context of changing the system's CSV delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it wouldn't be appropriate to *use* something like that except as a graphic element (which of course wouldn't be I18N'd in the first place, much less L10N'd). If you are trying to use it to e.g. indicate a ratio then you should have something like "%d / %d" instead, and localize the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Greek, questions end with a semicolon rather than ?, so essentially the `?` is replaced with `;` ... however, you should aim to always translate the question as a complete string including question mark anyway.